# How to loop through a list of urls using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello guys I want to loop the url in selenium every one times when it loop it have to change the url in the list when the chrome driver pop up here is my idea code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
List = ['http://facebook.com','http://youtube.com','http://google.com']
while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(List)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop through the list of urls using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import time

  url_list = ['http://facebook.com','http://youtube.com','http://google.com']
  for url in url_list:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
      driver.get(url)
      time.sleep(3)
      print(driver.title)
      driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Facebook – log in or sign up
  YouTube
  Google
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to reload the driver every time? I'd imagine that would cause the program to slow significantly if you have a large number of URL's (~1000)

Answer (score 0):

Try itertools.cycle() to infinitely loop through the list

```
from selenium import webdriver
import itertools
List = ['http://facebook.com','http://youtube.com','http://google.com']
for url in itertools.cycle(List):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.quit()
```

Use range() to limit the infinite loop.

Comment: Hey, man thanks you for help me out but when I try to do that it keeps looping in my chrome driver and keep switching the URL so I don't want like that I want it like when the driver quit and the URL switch to another one does not keep looping the URL in one time like that.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, the new code segment should work and will loop infinitely one url after the other