# Why selenium is not starting next url after quiting the previous url

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actully I'm working on some URLs. URLs are store in my database while picking one by one and looking for it resources and storing that resources in a database. if I do this with out using **driver.quit()** somehow for everyurl it store information from the beginning so I decide to use **driver.quit** now it work only for the first URL and does not work on second URL and so on. But currently I'm just printing the data to see it works according to me.
already check [How to loop through a list of urls using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799002/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-urls-using-selenium-and-python)

below is the part of code::

```
def select_url_test():
    http = 0
    https = 0

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    db_conn1 = Foreign_Key_table.database_conn()
    db_conn1.execute("SELECT url,id FROM SELECTED_URLS WHERE url_status = 'VALID' AND captcha_status = 'NO' LIMIT 2")
    urls = db_conn1.fetchall()

    for url_aa in urls:
        full_url = 'https://' + url_aa[0]  # url is in form of ('google.com' ,)
        # print(url[0])
        # print(full_url)
        driver.get(full_url)
        time.sleep(2)
        for request in driver.requests:    
            if request.url.startswith('https'):
                https += 1            
                print(request.url)
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: is there a need to put `driver.quit()` in the for loop? you can move this statement outside of for loop. i.e launch the driver , loop all the URLs, and then quit at last.

Comment: @simpleApp alreday tried this then actually it start for everyurl from the begining i.e list is `['google.com',facebook.com]` for `google.com` it works for when it comes to facebook.com it print again google.com and facebook.com data

Comment: how ```urls``` looks like ? and also could not find ```driver.requests``` pls post imports from your script.

Comment: are you using Selenium Wire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` into the loop. That's the line that actually opens chrome. So, at the end of the loop you do `driver.quit()`. That closes the browser. And at the beginning of each loop you need to open it again. So place `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` before `driver.get(full_url)` inside the loop.